# Night-Immune Huntsman

Tags: werewolv.es

If a Huntsman is immune to being killed at night (with Heart of Fenrir, Abyssal Armour or some other means), what happens when they successfully guard a target from a wolf?

Would they kill the attacking wolf without dying? Or does the sacrifice part of their ability bypass the immunity?

Comment: I think the huntsman will survive in this case, because he "redirects" the werewolf's attack to himself, where he would've survived. I'm not sure about it though.
Also be aware of the fact that questions concerning mechanics should directly not reference any on going game as this violates one of the site's rules of discussing active games outside of the game itself and could be considered cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Huntsman's guard ability triggers because of an attack, an `UnstoppableKill` is added against them, this ignores all possible modifiers of protection and immunity.

Because of this, the Huntsman would die in any scenario.

This interaction made sense when there were only protection roles in the game, and was intended to avoid triggering bizarre scenarios like chained huntsman defences. Since the introduction of items, this mechanic might need a revisit as part of a wider standardisation process to make resolutions more obvious and consistent for players to reason about.